# Slow swagger Scanning - s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner : Scanning for api listing references

Tags: swagger-ui, grpc-java

I am trying to add a grpc protofile to my swagger-ui.  I am consuming a grpc webservice which needs a protofile as input.  The input to my spring boot restful webservice needs to have that same grpc structure as its interface.  I recevied a jar from the individual that made the protofile and imported it to my webserivce.  When I try to add the @ResponseBody tag around the object from the protofile jar, my app hangs on this in the console at startup:

```
s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner    : Scanning for api listing references
```

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never return entity objects in controller method.

in my case. my Controller methods takes this parameter. 
"@AuthenticationPrincipal UserSession userSession"

when i exlude UserSession object swagger back to normal.
There were 2 way to do that

first is "@ApiIgnore @AuthenticationPrincipal UserSession userSession"

second is in swaggerConfig class
    private Class[] clazz = {UserSession.class};
    Docket().ignoredParameterTypes(clazz)

Answer (score 0):

Incase someone needs a solution, what I did was as a work around for now.

in my service's code (response is a String)

```
return JsonFormat.printer().print(myProtoObject);
```

in my client's code:

```
Builder b = ProtoObject.newBuilder();
JsonFormat.parser().merge(result.getBody(), b);
ProtoObject protoObject = b.build();
```